# probability of repeated events

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a website and I want to calculate the probability of clicks on the ads.

Let the probability that each user clicks on a link be `p` (something like `1%`)

if we have totally `N` users, What is the formula that computes the probability of exactly  `n` clicks?
of course we have

> 0< = n <= N

Each users can click only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider each user as a trial. For every trial you have two outcomes, they are success (clicks on ad) and failure (does not click on ad). $P[success] = p $ and $P[failure] = 1-p$.

The total number of ways in which $n$ users can be selected from $N$ users is $\binom{N}{n}$. So, the probability of exactly $n$ clicks is $\binom{N}{n}*p^n*(1-p)^m$ where $m = N-n$, as the clicks are independent and exactly $n$ clicks mean exactly $N-n$ 'not clicks'.

Comment: And this is called the binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes @Ken sure it is!.

Comment: Thanks @naive, is there any function to get (N n) for large Ns. (calculating N! for large Ns is impossible) an approximate function would be sufficient.

Comment: For large $N$ the binomial random variable can be described by a [Normal distribution](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/179/).